# Show that the Fermi surface is perpendicular to the Brillouin zone boundary in the nearly free electron approximation

Tags: condensed-matter, fermi-energy

How can one show that the Fermi surface is perpendicular to the Brillouin zone boundary in the nearly free electron approximation?

Similar question without an answer: [Why does the Fermi Surface cross the Brillouin zone boundary at right angles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109416/why-does-the-fermi-surface-cross-the-brillouin-zone-boundary-at-right-angles)

One of the answers discusses $\nabla_kE$; I have a proof which uses this but it doesn't explain where any of the terms come from - I was hoping someone could fill in the blanks to make it a more complete proof.

If $$\vec{\nabla_\vec{k}}E \cdot \vec{k} = 0$$ $$\vec{\nabla_\vec{k}}E \perp \vec{k}$$ $$\vec{\nabla_\vec{k}}E \perp \vec{E}$$ then $$E \parallel \vec{k}$$

Since $\vec{k}$ is perpedicular to the zone boundary $E$ must be too.

Comment: What is E here? Isn't energy?

Comment: Yes $E$ is the energy - I'm not entirely sure how energy can be a vector.

Comment: Then some of the formulas don't make sense.  The gradient of a scalar field is a vector but the field itself is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is a problem taken from Marder's condensed matter textbook. Anyway, credit goes to Sinova (notes [here](http://people.physics.tamu.edu/sinova/courses/oldcourses/P617/solutions_set2.PDF)).

In the nearly free electron model, the energy in the vicinity of a BZ boundary is given by $E = (E_\vec k ^0 + E_{\vec k + \vec K}^0) /2 \pm \sqrt{(E_\vec k ^0 + E_{\vec k + \vec K}^0)^2 /4 +|U_\vec K|^2}$. From there, you can compute the gradient as $\nabla _\vec k E$ and on the boundary of the BZ zone, it simplifies to $(\nabla _\vec k E_\vec k ^0 + \nabla _\vec k E_{\vec k + \vec K}^0) /2$ (because $E_\vec k ^0 = E_{\vec k +\vec K}^0$). This is equal to $\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}(2\vec k + \vec K)$.

The condition for being on the BZ boundary can be written as $2\vec k \cdot \vec K + K^2=0$ (which is just the previous expression dot $\vec K$, equals to 0). This is the equation of a plane with normal $\vec K$. And so we have shown that the gradient of the Fermi energy is perpendicular to a plane defined on the boundary of the BZ. This proves the title's question.