# Why should the group velocity be continuous?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electrons

I am trying to understand why the Fermi surface touches the Brillouin zone boundary at a right angle, and the only convincing answer I have seen without resorting to any particular model is [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/334321/), which claims that the group velocity $\nabla_{\boldsymbol{k}}E$ should be continuous. However, why must this be the case physically? Provided that energy and (crystal) momentum are conserved, what would be so bad about the electron discontinuously changing direction when you push it slightly?